# Why won't my css changes show without me restarting WEBrick?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, webrick

I am doing some simple css edits on a rails 3.2 project and my changes will not show up unless I restart webrick.

I came across something saying that it may be using the public/assets directory, but I don't think this is the case because my changes show when the server is restarted. Not sure why this is happening.

Does anyone know if there is some sort of configuration that I need to fix to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

run this command

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my development.rb file and now it works.

```
config.assets.digest = false
```